# Tree structures and directories

Tags: bash, directory-structure, tree

I need to draw the tree structure of the following code.

```
cd /; mkdir a b c a/a b/a; cd a; mkdir ../e ../a/f ../b/a/g; cd../b/./; mkdir /a/k a/b ../a/./b /c
```

I know that:  `cd /;` (goes to root) , `mkdir` creates directories a b c but I can't understand the rest of the line.

Any thoughts would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you try running the command? `cd../b/./;` will fail, that should be `cd ../b/./;`. But even the error messages will be informative. Just run the command and try to understand the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are ./ and ../ directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories) or also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is written in a confusing manner and I'm assuming comes from a basic linux/unix test. I can explain. It will seem clearer if it is on multiple lines. The ; char means end of a command. The mkdir command can do multiple things with one execution.

```
cd /
```

You will be in / as your current working directory.

```
mkdir a b c a/a b/a
```

Creates directories relative to your cwd: /a, /b, /c, /a/a, /b/a

```
cd a
```

Your cwd becomes /a

```
mkdir ../e ../a/f ../b/a/g
```

Creates directories relative to current location. The `..` means to go up one. Above your cwd of /a is / so you create /e, then /a/f, then /b/a/g dirs.

```
cd ../b/./
```

While `..` means parent directory, `.` means this directory. So, from /a you would go up one (`..`) then into /b, then stay where you are (`.`).

A trailing `/` after a directory name means only that it is a directory and is optional.

```
mkdir /a/k a/b ../a/./b /c
```

Again this needs to be broken up since it is obviously written to be confusing. Creates /a/k, since the leading `/` means an absolute path, then /b/a/b since you are already in /b and it is relative (does not start with /). Next is /a/b since you are already in /b and the `.` does nothing. Then it will try to create /c but this already exists.

I would suggest working through this yourself on a command line and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`tree` can visualize what you want, though your command will error as **terdon** pointed out. You'll need it to say `cd ../b/./;`

If you install `tree`, run your command, and run `tree` on your directories under `/` you'll see the full directory tree you've created.

```
[root@host /]# tree -a a
a
|-- a
|-- b
|-- f
`-- k

4 directories, 0 files
[root@host /]# tree -a b 
b
`-- a
    |-- b
    `-- g

3 directories, 0 files
[root@host /]# tree -a c
c

0 directories, 0 files
[root@host /]# tree -a e
e

0 directories, 0 files
```