# Why do I have both root and mongodb permisssions?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chown

These are permissions

```
total 8
7351455 drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 авг 21 10:36 .
7340101 drwxr-xr-x 69 root    root    4096 сеп  4 11:40 ..
```

for my `/var/lib/mongodb`

I am having problem with mongodb service,I found that I must run

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

df -T shows

```
df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   8145248        0   8145248   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      1634684     1904   1632780   1% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4     244567356 79042556 153031796  35% /
```

I think it is ext4.

Why?

Comment: What command did you run to obtain the output shown at the top of your question (e.g. `ls -al`)? What was the current working directory when you ran it?

Comment: I used ls -lia. It was /var/lib.

Comment: @fra-san Please,take a look at my edit.

Comment: 1) So, `ls -lia /var/lib/mongodb` lists two `.` entries, is this correct? This looks like a file system issue. What file system is `/var/lib/mongodb` on? 2) `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` will change the owner and group of `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` to `mongodb`, as in the listing you are showing. What makes you say that it didn't work?

Comment: @fra-san How to check /var/lib/mongodb filesystem?

Comment: ext4! Does this cause the issue?

Comment: @fra-san what do you mean? There's nothing strange here as far as I can tell, just one set of permissions for `/var/lib/mongodb` (shown as `.`) and another for `/var/lib` (shown as `..`). And I now see that change was added after your comment. Richard, do you still have a question?

Comment: I thought you had a file system issue because you were apparently listing two `.` entries in the same directory. Looking at your edited question I can't see any issue. Having a `.` and a `..` entries in any directory [is normal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63081/315749). You should probably rephrase your question: are you seeing error messages (either on programs or in log files)? What is not working as expected?

Comment: @fra-san Works fine.I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you ran

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

and than you found yourself puzzled because `ls -lia /var/lib/mongodb` also showed this entry:

```
7340101 drwxr-xr-x 69 root    root    4096 сеп  4 11:40 ..
```

That doesn't mean `chown` didn't work. Every directory on a Unix-like system has [these two entries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63081/315749): `.`, which is a hard link to the directory itself, and `..`, a hard link to its *parent* directory.

The above line from the output of `ls` refers to `/var/lib/mongodb`'s parent directory, `/var/lib`, which is still owned by root (as it should!).

Actually, the entry

```
7351455 drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 авг 21 10:36 .
```

confirms that `chmod` worked (or changed nothing because there was nothing to change).