# Special Characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash

What is the difference between `.` (or ..) and `~` character with respect to how they are treated by the bash?
If i use `~` character, bash expands it to absolute path but if is use `.` (or ..) bash does not expand it to absolute path?

My pwd is home directory. Now, when i run the command: `ls '.'` (or ls .) it shows me the contents of the pwd but if i run the command: `ls '~'`, it gives the error that the file or directory does not exists.
This means `~` is expanded by shell before passing it to the `ls` command but `.` is not.
Is `.` not a special character? When is `.` (or ..) treated as special character and expanded by the shell?

Comment: Related: [What are `./` and `../` directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63081/108618)

Comment: `~` is only special when it is unquoted and when it is the first character of a word -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion

Comment: `.` and `..` are not special to bash in any way, so they are the same quoted or unquoted.

Comment: See also [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot `.` isn't a special character in the shell. All the properties of the `.` and `..` directory links are just about the filesystem structure, the shell has nothing to do with it. Note that even there, it's not the character, but those two specific names. `foo.txt`, `.bar` and `...` are regular file names, even if the ones starting with a dot are treated specially by globs and `ls`.

On the other hand, `~` is a regular character for the filesystem, but in the shell [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) treats it specially. So an unquoted `~` at the start of a word gets expanded to the current user's home directory, and `~foo` gets expanded to the home directory of user `foo`.

(Of course the shell does know about what `.` and `..` are, in that running `cd ..` from `/tmp` doesn't make the current working directory show as `/tmp/..`, but as `/`. Also, unlike letters and `_`, the dot isn't valid in variable names, like e.g. `,`, `%` and `-` aren't.)

Answer (score 1):

`~` as stand-alone - that is unquoted - is interpreted by the shell as being the home directory. When you quote it, that interpretation stops, so it is not like ordinary variables.

`.` and `..` are references in the file system.

So, if you try to use `.` in a C program (so without the shell) that would work, as in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(".");  /*<---------------See the . for current dir */
  if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

whereas if you try that with `~`, (`d = opendir("~");`) that won't work.